# How to remove a very large portion of DOM with IE in small amount of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

When user push a refresh buttton I must remove a table from the actual page and then reload via ajax a new one, and then show the new one.

I enclosed the ajax-loaded TABLE into a DIV with a known id.

When user push the Refresh button, i simply do this:

```
document.getElementById('result_div').innerHTML = '';
```

Actually FF takes 1 seconds, Chrome 2 and IE about 10 seconds and it's freezing, so my users are very very angry because of this problem.

Is there a faster whay to remove an entire very large table from the page?

Comment: Refer: https://coderwall.com/p/nygghw/don-t-use-innerhtml-to-empty-dom-elements

Comment: @RayonDabre This is what is used in jQuery for `empty()` method `while ( elem.firstChild ) {
    elem.removeChild( elem.firstChild );
   }`

Comment: @A.Wolff, Any better approach ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Not sure but i'd say no :)

Comment: If what you are removing is most of the page you might actually find it faster to re-Ajax the entire page in its updated form.

Comment: I'm already reloading the content via ajax. the problem is that it's time consuming and so the paying user asked me to removed actual content, than reload the new one, then show the just loaded new content. so the problem is how to fas remove a very big table. I find a better way googling and googling and googling: I loop through TBODY descendants and then remove it. Absurdely, it's faster then removing at all the innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very end, I'm using this solution.

First I remove from the `TBODY` every single `TR`

```
container = document.getElementById('result_table_body');
if (container) {
    var len = container.childNodes.length;
    while (len--) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    };
}
```

Then I removed in bulk what is remaining in the `div` used as results container

```
$('#result_div').html('');
```

I found this snippet here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-empty-vs-html/14

I didn't want to believe, but it's faster than emptying `innerHTML`, and it's faster than jQuery `empty()` function (this in IE 11, my pecific critical case, FF doesn't have any problem with 1 milion cells to remove using empty, innerHTML or waht else... ).